# Models in physics

Tags: terminology, approximations, models

As I said in another question I am just a physics enthusiast so I am sorry for my very poor knowledge. What is meant by [models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_modelling) in physics? what is their function and why physicists imply them? 
Are the actual phenomena the exact reproduction in the real world of a physical model?

Comment: https://www.sciencelearn.org.nz/resources/575-scientific-modelling should be helpful

Answer (score 4):

A model in physics usually means a mathematical description of a system which is used to make testable predictions about its behavior. When writing about physics, some people prefer the term "model" over "theory" because most non-physicists don't know the difference between "theory" in the scientific sense and in its everyday usage.

All models are approximations to actual behavior, shown to be relevant and useful in prescribed sets of circumstances. "Adding more physics" to a model usually means accounting for more subtle physical effects by including them in the math, in the interests of improving the model's accuracy.

Sometimes, making a model more accurate a representation of the real world requires it to be fundamentally rewritten, as for example in the case of our understanding of gravity. Newton's original formulation was the first mathematical treatment of gravity and is perfectly useful today in predicting the movements of planets and satellites, but fails when called on to account for the behavior of extremely massive or extremely fast-moving things. Einstein's formulation of gravity encompasses the Newtonian treatment and also gives useful results in these special cases.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I chortled a little when I realized that by this definition string theory isn't a model as it has not generated testable predictions - and indeed, it's right in there the name: theory. Until now I had naively assumed it was a model. (Note: I'm an experimentalist)

Comment: your comments about string theory are spot-on. Have you read Smolin's book about it called "The Trouble With Physics"?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, given that "All models are approximations to actual behaviour" it is correct to say that  physical phenomena are never the exact counterpart of their correspondent models? In a nutshell, are physical phenomena the exact copy in nature of the model?

Comment: The deeper you go into the math, the more closely the models resemble reality i.e., the simpler the relationships get (fewer messy details)- but you can almost always find a set of circumstances where the model must fail. for example, any term with (distance)^2 in the denominator is destined to fail as distance -> zero.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I haven't read that book, do you recommend it? I'm always looking for a good book!

Comment: highly recommended- also the one by Peter Woit called "Not Even Wrong", same topic but written from the technical viewpoint of a heavy-duty mathematical physicist.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I started reading Smolin and it's insightful, I'm enjoying it. I'll also read Woit. I love reading books like that, written by experts (and somewhat for 'experts'), so my sincere thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: most excellent, Sabrina!